# How to drag HTML nodes inside another nodes with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to be able to drag and drop HTML nodes into other nodes. For example, if I start with this HTML structure:

```
<div class="first">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Some content</p>
</div>
<div class="second">
  <h2>Subtitle</h2>
</div>
```

I need to be able to select the `<h1>` or the `<p>` tag and drag any of those inside of `div.second`.
So the result would be:

```
<div class="first">
  <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
<div class="second">
  <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  <p>Some content</p>
</div>
```

As a (optional) plus, I need a placeholder in drop area. Before dropping the `<p>` tag into destination, place a copy of it to see how it will look like.

How can it be done with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not keen enough to learn about HTML5 drag and drop API (which I recommend reading up on, though it's a bit buggy), just use jQuery UI's drag/drop: http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

Comment: jQuery will not be used in the project, but YUI. I'll choose a plain JS or YUI solution. On the other hand, I'm keen enough to learn the HTML5 drag and drop API, I'm just not familiarized with it. Did a little research, but judging on all the examples I found, didn't seemed to me that it can be used for draging and changing HTML nodes position in the document. Do you have any idea or suggestion of some article to read in that direction?